# Laravel – load pivot information between 2 models

Tags: laravel

I have the default auth User model and a Course model:

```
class Course extends Model{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
  }
}
```

On the `course_user` pivot table I have some extra data (`completed` – so, course_id, user_id, completed).

I have In a route, I use route model binding to load the Course. What I'd like to do is something as close as possible to this:

```
class CourseController extends Controller{
  public function show(Course $course)
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->loadPivot($course);
    return Auth::user()->course->completed;
  }
}
```

Is there any such function? It just feels crazy that I already have the two models in question. At the moment, I know I *can* do it with something closer to this monstrosity:

```
return $course
          ->users()
          ->withPivot('complete')
          ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
          ->first()
          ->pivot
          ->complete;
```

Comment: you can use pivot on the model and get the pivot table object. then you may get all the data from the pivot table

Comment: How far into this courseware project are you?  I've gotta finish up a laravel/vue courseware blade admin with vue ui over the weekend before me next gig.  Perhaps we can collaborate for fun and profit.  It's going up ... soon at CourseController.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to recommend a different path to solving this issue, that I believe will make your domain more descriptive and your application more flexible.

Often times, if you find yourself needing additional columns in a pivot table beyond the required foreign keys, you're actually seeing a need for another **model**.

In this scenario, a User doesn't really have or own a Course - they *enroll*.

Create an `Enrollment` model, with `belongsTo` foreign keys for User and Course. Add in the supplemental attributes/columns needed such as completed status, when they joined, anything else that makes sense. Add `hasMany` relationships from both `User` and `Course` models to `Enrollment`.

Now, when you have the User and Course and need to find the middle, it's easy:

```php
$enrollment = $user->enrollments()
    ->where('course_id', $course->id)
    ->first();

// If $enrollment is NULL, they don't belong to this Course

dd($enrollment->completed);
```

Some of the benefits going this direction:

- Your application's domain is more descriptive, and represents a real-world situation more closely
- A User can enroll in a Course more than once
- Queries are simpler for finding individual enrollments and getting their supplemental data (no pivot silliness)